# How to not have .axd files authenticate in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis

We recently moved from IIS6 to IIS7 and we're experiencing some issues.  The nastiest seems to be that .axd files being handled differently in IIS7.  They're run through the pipeline for the authentication and authorization modules as well as the global.asax events.  This causes problems for a variety of reason (specific to our code) that won't go into.

How can we just exclude .axd files from all this like they were in IIS6?  Thanks.

Note: We're still in 32bit Classic pipeline mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this in your web.config

```
<location path="name_of_handler.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This worked for me! thank you .
Can't believe I didn't try it before.